# Design a PID Controller

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I need to design a prefilter and PID controller for a plant whose transfer function is given by

$$G(s)=\frac{3}{s(s^2+4s+5)}$$

subject to the following performance requirements:

1. An acceleration error constant of $K_a=2$.
2. Phase margin equal to $45$ degrees.
3. A bandwidth greater than $2.8\ \text{rad}/s$.

I only have an idea about how to use the acceleration error constant to calculate the $K_i$ to be $3.3333$ based on the theory of steady-state error, but I do not know how to use it for the other two requirements.

Comment: Can you give the general form of a PID controller? Can you state the definition of bandwidth and phase margin? Given your I term, how might you design the P and D terms to achieve the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

The issue of compensation is quite broad, there are several techniques to address it. Here we will stick to the basic concepts of closed loop stability.

Calling

$$
G(s) = \frac{3}{s(s^2+4s+5)}\\
PID(s) = \frac{K_i}{s}+s K_d + K_p
$$

we have the stability conditions

$$
\left|G(j\omega_c)PID(j\omega_c)\right| = 1\\
\angle G(j\omega_c)PID(j\omega_c) = -\pi+\phi
$$

where $\omega_c$ defines practically the bandwidth and $\phi$ the phase margin

Considering also the steady state acceleration error as

$$
\lim_{s\to 0}s \left(1-\frac{G\cdot PID}{1+G\cdot PID}\right)\frac{1}{s^3} = \frac{5}{3K_i}
$$

we have three conditions and three parameters to determine or

$$
\frac{9 \left(K_d^2 \omega _c^4+\omega _c^2 \left(K_p^2-2 K_d K_i\right)+K_i^2\right)}{\omega _c^4
   \left(\omega _c^4+6 \omega _c^2+25\right)}=1\\
\frac{\omega _c \left(\omega _c^2 (K_p-4 K_d)+4 K_i-5 K_p\right)}{K_d \omega _c^4+5 K_i-\omega _c^2 (5 K_d+K_i-4
  K_p)}=-\tan\phi\\
\frac{5}{3K_i}= \frac{1}{K_a}
$$

now with $\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}, \omega_c = 3, K_a = 2$ solving for $K_p,K_d, K_i$ we obtain

$$
K_p = 5.66, K_d = 4.14, K_i = 3.33
$$

Follows the close loop response showing in in red $G(s)$ and in blue $PID(s)G(s)$

[image]

The overshoot issue can be handled with a proper prefilter and we leave it to the reader.

Comment: The phase margin is defined at the cross-over frequency $\omega_c$ where the absolute value of the open-loop gain is $1$, so a bit odd to set it to $1/\sqrt{2}$, which is the absolute value at the bandwidth $\omega_b$. Sure, bandwidth and cross-over frequency are fairly close, but as you've defined the controller now, it will not have the requested phase margin.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg The phase margin now is $50^{\circ }$ a little better than $45^{\circ }$ Considering $|G PID| = 1$ of course the phase margin will be $45^{\circ }$.

Comment: Yes, that follows directly as your approach effectively will phase-advance in the wrong frequency where you've lost more phase, leading to more phase advancing than required.